# Broadcast a UDP string with Python

Tags: python, udp, broadcast

I intend to broadcast UDP strings to the local network, using Python. What is the most straightforward way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#module-socket) python module

Please see below code from [UdpComminication](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) wiki

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE.encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Comment: Thank you for the immediate answer. However, the script returns:
    'Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Adriano\Google Drive\python\socketTest.py", line 13, in <module>
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
'

Comment: I should add: it's Python 3.4, and the OS is Windows 8.1

Comment: Please paste full traceback.

Comment: That was actually the entire traceback, poorly formatted though. Here is another attempt:

`UDP target IP: 127.0.0.1
 UDP target port: 5005
 message: Hello, World!'

' Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adriano\Google Drive\python\socketTest.py", line 13, in <module>
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: here is solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781639/typeerror-str-does-not-support-buffer-interface also updated my answer.

Comment: enjoy python codding :)