# Python 3: server error: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, server, typeerror

I got stuck on an error which I didn't have when I've done something similar in python 2.

Here is the code:

```
def computeSha(self,reqFile):
    filesize_bytes = os.path.getsize(reqFile)

    s = sha1()
    s.update(("blob %u\0" % filesize_bytes).encode('utf-8'))

    with open(reqFile, 'rb') as f:
        s.update(f.read())

    s = s.hexdigest()
    print ("here is the sha: " + s)
    return s

def _sendSha(self, component_id):
    component_path = db_connector.get_design_path(component_id)
    sha = self.computeSha(component_path)

    self.connection.send(self._adjustLength(len(sha)))
    self.connection.sendall(data)
```

The error appears here: self.connection.send(self._adjustLength(len(sha)))

Here is the code for adjustLength:

```
def _adjustLength(self, length):
    #max size is 8 bytes long
    length = str(length)
    if DEBUG:
        print("_adjustLength before:" + length)
    while len(length) < 8:
        length = "0"+length
    length = length+"\n"
    if DEBUG:
        print("_adjustLength after:" + length)
    return length
```

Comment: Where are you setting `self.connection`?

Comment: Please include the error you're asking about in the question. By that I mean the full traceback.

Comment: I think we're going to need the code for `self._adjustLength()`.

Comment: But generally, this looks like a bytes versus unicode issue.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mp69hYU2 here's the full traceback

Comment: @spoke, please include it directly in the question.

Comment: This question looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781639/typeerror-str-does-not-support-buffer-interface

Comment: Try replacing `self.connection.send(self._adjustLength(len(sha)))` with `self.connection.send(self._adjustLength(len(sha)).encode())`.

Comment: @Cyphase it worked. thank's a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
self.connection.send(self._adjustLength(len(sha)))
```

with this:

```
self.connection.send(self._adjustLength(len(sha)).encode())
```

In Python 3, unicode strings are now the default. Sockets expect byte strings, so you have to convert the unicode strings to byte strings. You do that with `.encode()`.

I am glossing over a bit (a lot) that's not directly relevant to the question. [Ned Batchelder's Unipain talk](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) is a good resource though.